# Split count metric by delta across time interval in Graphite

Tags: graphite

I have a counter metric, which I will call `a.metric.count`

When graphed normally this would be an ever-increasing upwards line, which is not that useful. What I would like is to show the number of events which occurred every hour.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `derivative` function, as documented here: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.derivative

That will, at each data point, show how much the value increased from the previous timeseries datapoint.

If you want to view it on a per-hour basis, you can use `summarize`, as documented here: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize

So, to view the hourly increase in .count, you could do:

`summarize(derivative(a.metric.count), "1hour")`

Comment: What happens when my "ever-increasing" counter drops to zero at some point (hangout, etc..), should I use ```nonNegativeDerivative``` instead of ```derivative``` for the same cause ?

Answer (score 2):

Also using diffSeries, but results in a little bit of a nicer graph:

```
diffSeries(
    sumSeries(a.metric.count),
    sumSeries(timeShift(a.metric.count, "1h"))
)
```

If you want to avoid the ending spike you can use a double offset:

```
diffSeries(
    sumSeries(timeShift(a.metric.count, "1h")),
    sumSeries(timeShift(a.metric.count, "2h"))
)
```

Keep in mind that with this method you will be behind by the smaller offset.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need two different graphs:

- `a.metric.count`
- `timeShift(a.metric.count, "1h")`

Next we need to summarise these by hour, using the last value recorded for each hour:

- `summarize(a.metric.count, "1h", "last")`
- `summarize(timeShift(a.metric.count, "1h"), "1h", "last")`

Now we just need to show the difference between the two graphs:

`diffSeries(summarize(timeShift(a.metric.count, "1h"), "1h", "last"), summarize(a.metric.count, "1h", "last"))`

The only trouble with this approach is that the data for the latest hour is wrong because there is no "last" value on the non-timeshifted graph, which means that the graph will spike